# How to retrieve data from access database with serial no. using vba?

Tags: vba

I have a excel workbook and a access database. See below image: -

[image]

Is there any way or method to retrieve data from access database to excel sheet by there serial number.

**For example**

if I type 16 in sr. no. field then all related cell should be populate with their related data.
**Like**

> Company: Mayank
>
> Location: Shimla
>
> Contact: 6325859647

Descriptions, Quantity, Rate Total etc.

As shown in image.

or if i type 15 in serial number field then
Details Should Be Like

> Company: Samar
>
> Location: Bhiwari
>
> Contact: 6325859647

Descriptions, Quantity, Rate Total
etc.

**Below code is for retrieve data between two dates.**

```
Sub Demo()
Dim cn As Object, rst As Object
Dim sDate As Date, eDate As Date
Dim strQuery As String
Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
sDate = DateSerial(2006, 3, 30)
eDate = DateSerial(2006, 4, 25)
With cn
    .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
    .ConnectionString = "Data Source=C:\Test\Northwind.accdb"
    .Open
End With

strQuery = "SELECT * FROM [Inventory Transactions] Where [Transaction Created Date] Between #" & sDate & "# and #" & eDate & "#"
Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rst.Open strQuery, cn, 1, 3
[A1].CopyFromRecordset rst
rst.Close
cn.Close
End Sub
```

**Any Help will be appreciates.**